# Using regression to solve an expenditure minimization problem

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, optimization, econometrics, controlling-for-a-variable

I'm working with some data and I want to choose capital and labour expenditures in order to minimize total expenditures subject to the constraint that they produce a certain level of output. The issue is that I don't know what the production function is and there are a lot of different other input variables that determine output in this sector, though I suspect capital and labour expenditures are both positively related to output.

My question is, can I use a regression framework to solve this problem? In particular, can I regress total expenditures on the capital-to-labour ratio while controlling for output? My thinking is that this will allow me to see how much labour could be substituted for capital (or vice versa) in order to produce the same level of output. Does this approach make sense?

Comment: I'd start by looking at plots of 'output' vs 'capital' and 'output' vs 'labor'.

Comment: The output vs. labour plot seems to show a consistent relationship. The current year capital vs. output plot has a weaker relationship, but using lagged values for capital and plotting against output gives a tighter link.